# package activeMq with tomcat (java)

Tags: java, activemq-classic

In my application,i have activeMq to send the message from client to server and vice versa.I run it as a standalone server.So when a client machine sends the message,the messages are passed in the activeMq queue and then retrieve by the server(my Application) if and only if the transaction is done locally,meaning the client machine and server(my application) live in the same computer. But when i run the client and server from two different computer meaning server in one and client in another then the client can only establish connection to the server but the messages are not passed to the activeMq queue.I think this is something with activeMq problem.

can anyone tell me how to solve this?
thanks

here is the code which passes the data sent by client to the queue.

```
package event.activeMq;  
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.Arrays;  
import java.util.Date;  
import java.util.Iterator;  

import javax.jms.Connection;  
import javax.jms.DeliveryMode;  
import javax.jms.Destination;  
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;  
import javax.jms.Session;  
import javax.jms.TextMessage;  

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;  
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;  
import org.apache.activemq.console.command.store.amq.CommandLineSupport;  
import org.apache.activemq.util.IndentPrinter;  

public class ProducerTool extends Thread {

    private Destination destination;
    private int messageCount = 1;
    private long sleepTime;
    private boolean verbose = true;
    private int messageSize = 1000;
    private static int parallelThreads = 1;
    private long timeToLive;
    private String user = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_USER;
    private String password = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_PASSWORD;
    private String url = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL;
    private String subject = "CLOUDD.DEFAULT";
    private boolean topic;
    private boolean transacted;
    private boolean persistent;
    private static Object lockResults = new Object();
    private static String DateTime="";
    private static String TaskID="";
    private static String UniqueEventID="";
    private static String Generator="";
    private static String GeneratorBuildVsn="";
    private static String Severity="";
    private static String EventText="";
    private static String SubsystemID="";
    private static String EventNumber="";
    private static String atmId="";


   public void element(String[] element) {  
       this.DateTime = element[0];  
       this.TaskID = element[1];  
       this.Generator = element[2];  
       this.Severity = element[3];  
       this.EventText = element[4];  
       this.SubsystemID = element[5];  
       this.EventNumber = element[6];  
       this.GeneratorBuildVsn = element[7];  
       this.UniqueEventID = element[8];  
       this.atmId = element[9];  
   }  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        System.out.println("came here");  
        ArrayList<ProducerTool> threads = new ArrayList();  
        ProducerTool producerTool = new ProducerTool();  
        producerTool.element(args);  

        producerTool.showParameters();  
        for (int threadCount = 1; threadCount <= parallelThreads; threadCount++) {  
            producerTool = new ProducerTool();  
            CommandLineSupport.setOptions(producerTool, args);  
            producerTool.start();  
            threads.add(producerTool);  
        }  

        while (true) {  
            Iterator<ProducerTool> itr = threads.iterator();  
            int running = 0;  
            while (itr.hasNext()) {  
                ProducerTool thread = itr.next();  
                if (thread.isAlive()) {  
                    running++;  
                }  
            }
            if (running <= 0) {
                System.out.println("All threads completed their work");
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public void showParameters() {
        System.out.println("Connecting to URL: " + url);
        System.out.println("Publishing a Message with size " + messageSize + " to " + (topic ? "topic" : "queue") + ": " + subject);
        System.out.println("Using " + (persistent ? "persistent" : "non-persistent") + " messages");
        System.out.println("Sleeping between publish " + sleepTime + " ms");
        System.out.println("Running " + parallelThreads + " parallel threads");

        if (timeToLive != 0) {
          //  System.out.println("Messages time to live " + timeToLive + " ms");
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            // Create the connection.
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(user, password, url);
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();

            // Create the session
            Session session = connection.createSession(transacted, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            if (topic) {
                destination = session.createTopic(subject);
            } else {
                destination = session.createQueue(subject);
            }

            // Create the producer.
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
            if (persistent) {
                producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
            } else {
                producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
            }
            if (timeToLive != 0) {
                producer.setTimeToLive(timeToLive);
            }

            // Start sending messages
            sendLoop(session, producer);

           // System.out.println("[" + this.getName() + "] Done.");

            synchronized (lockResults) {
                ActiveMQConnection c = (ActiveMQConnection) connection;
               // System.out.println("[" + this.getName() + "] Results:\n");
                c.getConnectionStats().dump(new IndentPrinter());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
           // System.out.println("[" + this.getName() + "] Caught: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (Throwable ignore) {
            }
        }
    }  

    protected void sendLoop(Session session, MessageProducer producer) throws Exception {

        for (int i = 0; i < messageCount || messageCount == 0; i++) {

            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(createMessageText(i));
            if (verbose) {
                String msg = message.getText();
                if (msg.length() > 50) {
                    msg = msg.substring(0, 50) + "...";
                }
              //  System.out.println("[" + this.getName() + "] Sending message: '" + msg + "'");
            }

            producer.send(message);

            if (transacted) {
              //  System.out.println("[" + this.getName() + "] Committing " + messageCount + " messages");
                session.commit();
            }
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        }
    }

    private String createMessageText(int index) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(messageSize);

        buffer.append("DateTime "+DateTime+" EventNumber "+EventNumber+" TaskID "+TaskID+" AtmId "+atmId+
                " Generator "+Generator+" GeneratorBuildVsn "+GeneratorBuildVsn+" Severity "+Severity+
                " UniqueEventID "+UniqueEventID+" EventText "+EventText+" SubsystemID "+SubsystemID+" End ");
        if (buffer.length() > messageSize) {
            return buffer.substring(0, messageSize);
        }
        for (int i = buffer.length(); i < messageSize; i++) {
            buffer.append(' ');
        }

        DateTime="";
        EventNumber="";
        TaskID="";
        atmId="";
        Generator="";
        GeneratorBuildVsn="";
        Severity="";
        UniqueEventID="";
        EventText="";
        SubsystemID="";

        return buffer.toString();        
    }

    public void setPersistent(boolean durable) {
        this.persistent = durable;
    }

    public void setMessageCount(int messageCount) {
        this.messageCount = messageCount;
    }

    public void setMessageSize(int messageSize) {
        this.messageSize = messageSize;
    }

    public void setPassword(String pwd) {
        this.password = pwd;
    }

    public void setSleepTime(long sleepTime) {
        this.sleepTime = sleepTime;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public void setTimeToLive(long timeToLive) {
        this.timeToLive = timeToLive;
    }

    public void setParallelThreads(int parallelThreads) {
        if (parallelThreads < 1) {
            parallelThreads = 1;
        }
        this.parallelThreads = parallelThreads;
    }

    public void setTopic(boolean topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    public void setQueue(boolean queue) {
        this.topic = !queue;
    }

    public void setTransacted(boolean transacted) {
        this.transacted = transacted;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void setVerbose(boolean verbose) {
        this.verbose = verbose;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your questin with answers on this questions:

- What os do you use?
- Do you have a firewall like software on pc?
- Could you provide here ActiveMQ conf file?
- Could you provide a function
  which implemented connection establishment?

upd:
   I do't understand all your logic but i thk bug here:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception e){    
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And never never never catch all exceptions! it's very dangerous. 
if you want to catch exception, you need to handle it.

Comment: i use windows 7,yes i have a firewall.

Comment: the connection between server and client is made by tcp/ip sockets